# Standard for Second Preimage Resistant Hash Functions

Tags: hash

Some PQC schemes don't require collision resistance for their hash functions, thus using a hash function faster than the SHA series that only considers the pre-image and secondary pre-image resistance would speed up these schemes.

Is there such a standard for hash functions that 1st and 2nd preimage resistant but not necessarily collision resistant?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking? However, see [Why does NIST say that 2nd preimage resistance depends on the message length](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87197/18298)

Comment: Im asking if ONLY 2nd preimage resistant hash functions exist, which, due to their 2nd preimage security only, are faster than SHA-2/3. Some pqc schemes dont require collision resistance for thei hash functions, thus using a faster than SHA2~ scheme would speed up these schemes

Comment: BLAKE2 is one of the fastest. And a better question should be included at least the names of these PQC schemes. Note that, hash functions are designed for collision resistance.

Comment: I guess the question is if you can create one that *doesn't* have collision resistance but is faster. I guess you could e.g. halve the state / output.

Comment: Ok, I took the liberty to edit your question. Could you check it?